# Unexpected 'NameError' while assignment of an input variable to be a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, variables

I have a variable with an input, and it´s all ok, i made the variable global with the 'global [variable]' statement, and later, i made a dictionary with a key called 'Nome:' and the value the variable 'nome_civ_1', but python is saying in a 'NameError' that 'nome_civ_1' is not defined.

I´ve tried first making the variable 'global', because it´s in a function, and i think it worked, but, python is still saying that 'nome_civ_1' is not defined.

I´ve searched for a misspelled keyword or something, but i´m not finding anything of this type.

```
 print("Preencha os Seguintes Parâmetros Para Começar a Jogar:")
    print()

    global nome_civ_1
    global sis_gov_1 # Other Variable 
    global turnos_máximos # Other Variable 

    nome_civ_1 = input("Nome da sua Civilização: ")
```

```
dados_civ_1 = {"Nome:" : nome_civ_1, # The "Name Error" line. 
               "Sistema de Governo:" : sis_gov_1,
               "Sistema Estelar:" : "", # The "" is just to avoid an syntax error
               "Nome do Planeta:" : "", 

               # More Keys and Values
```

The expected output of this was simply that this dict assigned the variable as the value, then, i would use this dict for a further use.

But, this is i´m getting, a 'NameError' of cause that i can´t see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i made the variable global with the 'global [variable]' statement

You actually didn't. `global` only applies to variables that have already been defined in the global scope. You can't insert a variable into global scope from within a local scope:

```
>>> def test():
...     global loc
...     loc = 5
...     
>>> loc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'loc' is not defined
```

However, you can *mark* existing global variables as `global` inside a function so that when you assign to them, Python doesn't create a new local variable, but changes the value of that *existing* global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `global` statement [does not "define" variables](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/global.html).

> `global`... means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

In your function above, `nome_civ_1` is not bound to any object. The `global` statement merely states that, if you bound it to an object, the binding will affect also the scope outside the function.